# How do you pass on the google client id from one page to another?

Tags: .htaccess

I have a website that when opened through a google ad has the gclid appended to the url. But when i click on the links within the homepage to open up a new page, I lose the gclid. Is there a way to pass on the gclid from one page to another. I think it has to be from the .htaccess file but not sure how to do it. My .htaccess file looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this, not from the .htaccess file but using the php session. I have several pages for the website and each of them has the same form. So, basically I stored the gclid parameter inside the session variable that was accessible on every page because each page had the session info. This way I was able to retrieve the gclid parameter in the form and ultimately store it into the database.